# Creating user tokens for API access (with Auth0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt, auth0

I have an existing (Rails) application which we're looking to add an API to.  We therefore have an existing user base which is currently managed by Auth0.

With our API we would like users to be able to get a token from our dashboard, and then use that token to access our API on a semi-long lived basis.  Considering we're already using Auth0 to manage our users and authentication it would be prudent to have them also authenticate requests to our API.

We could roll our own Bearer token system and skip Auth0 altogether or use the JWT system that Auth0 uses, although it's not clear how that relates to individual users and identifying them.

What would be the best approach here?  Should we use Auth0 and if so, how can we make it work how we'd like?

Comment: Are you using the Devise gem in your application? If yes, I think you could consider managing your own token system by using Devise and the Grape API. It's very straightforward and easy to implement. Managing the users by the application or yourself is considered a good practice, as there are many features and options available with Devise for authentication and user management.